# Enabling TLS and TLS-MA simultaneously for different clients of a Oracle DB

Tags: oracle-12c, authentication, jdbc, tls-1.2

We have a requirement where we want to enable **TLS-MA** for some of the clients connecting to a specific Oracle database while the other clients can continue to use **TLS** with server certificate.

- We are using Oracle 12.c in our environment.
- Clients are connecting using the jdbc thin driver

I am an Oracle noob and i am not able to understand the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-secure-sockets-layer-authentication.html#GUID-EF8DEC69-C8BE-462B-ABDD-E621914E617E)

Will it work if i create 2 listeners; one with
`SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=TRUE`
and another with
`SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE`

Any pointer to reference documentation will be great.

Answer (score 1):

SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION is a sqlnet.ora parameter - effectively a property of the database itself - not a listener parameter. You can only have one value per database instance (stand-alone or container), so there is no way to have the parameter set differently for separate clients. What you are attempting cannot be done as far as I know.